# How to inject my code to a website automatically like run code in chrome inspect console?

Tags: jquery, console, inject, inspect

There is a website(I don't have control) that there are JQuery functions to POST data for insert database, I want write a program that when my page loaded data send to those functions. I can do this with console of browsers, now I want do this automatically and via load a page.

Comment: You'd need to create a browser extension to do this: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts for example

Comment: Do you can explain more?

Comment: How I can create my extension and run that with reload my special page?

Comment: Start by reading the documentation I just linked you to, and following the "getting started" tutorial.  If you get stuck, post a specific question here. This isn't a free coding service; questions that boil down to "write my code for me" don't tend to go well.

Comment: I looking for a function that gives 2 parameters (URL & codes) and do this operation with load my own page.

Comment: You may want to read these: [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: But, I didn't say "write my code" bro, I just say I looking for a function that arrive me to my goal. I think, If wrote this function before, it is vain to rewrite it again ;)
Excuse me my bad English ;)

Comment: So you don't want someone to write your code, you just want someone to have already written your code.  OK then!  Good luck!

Comment: Don't use OS, because It was written before, try to write your OS :)))))

Comment: I created my extension, and now, can I call my extension in my page?? (The code which I want when my page load, the extension execute)